# using jquery to make class active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul id="tab" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#feed" data-toggle="tab">Feed</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#dashboard" data-toggle="tab">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When a user clicks the link below. i want to change the #dashboard li to active, and remove active from the #feed li. how do i do this?

```
<a href=".showfollowers" onclick='load_followers();' data-toggle="tab">See All</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You better use unobtrusive javascript:

```
<a href=".showfollowers" id="foo" data-toggle="tab">See All</a>
```

**Code:**

```
$('#foo').click(function(){
        $('#dashboard').addClass('active');
        $('#feed').removeClass('active');
        load_followers();
        return false; // if needed.
    });
```

Though it can be done with inline scripts, inline code is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="tabs">
              <ul id="tab" class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li class="active"><a href="#feed" data-toggle="tab">Feed</a></li>
              <li><a href="dashboard" data-toggle="tab">Dashboard</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>

<a href="showfollowers" onclick='load_followers();' data-toggle="tab">See All</a>


$('.showfollowers').click(function(){
  $(#tab li).removeClass('active');
  $('#dashboard').parent().addClass('active');

})
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is:

```
$("#tab li").removeClass("active");
$("#dashboard").parent().addClass("active");
```

This will firstly remove class "active" for all of 'li' elements then add it to the li element of #dashboard tab.

The other way is to use siblings() function.

```
var dashboard = $("#dashboard").parent(),
    siblings = dashboard.siblings();
siblings.removeClass("active");
dashboard.addClass("active")
```

Answer (score 1):

may this helps you... find more about toggle class http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

```
$("[href='showfollowers']").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault(); 
   $("#tab li").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add `id` to the element so that it will nbe easy to identify elements.

```
<div class="tabs">
   <ul id="tab" class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li id="liFeed" class="active"><a href="#feed" data-toggle="tab">Feed</a></li>
     <li id="lidashboard""><a href="#dashboard" data-toggle="tab">Dashboard</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tab" id="aSeeAll" >See All</a>
```

Script

```
$(function(){
  $("#aSeeAll").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab li").removeClass("active");
    $("#lidashboard").addClass("active");
  });    
});
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/H2BBn/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.tabs li").eq(1).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
```

Comment: If you remove first, there is no need to look up siblings. `$("div.tabs li").removeClass("active").eq(1).addClass("active");`

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solutions above worked only partially for me. The tab changed to active but the new content didn't show. Here's what I ended up with:

```
$('.ext-butt-class').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".nav-tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $("[href='#requiredtab']").parent().addClass("active");
});
```

.where `.ext-butt-class` is added to the link that's triggering the switch and `#requiredtab` is the a-name of the tab we're trying to target.

Hope that helps someone else using Roots Wordpress Framework and/or Twitter Bootstrap.